# PostgreSQL is there a way to use PostGIS.ST_Contains() with PostGIS.ST_Collect()?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

In PostgreSQL, I have a table of geometries. I want to take a union of the geometries, perhaps from 0 to more geometries. There is a PostGIS function called ST_Collect() that collects geometries so I have this SQL:

```
 SELECT PostGIS.ST_Collect( ARRAY(SELECT mk.geom FROM mydatatable mk WHERE mk.id in ('002', '003', '007')));
```

Is it possible to use this collection in a PostGIS function called ST_Contain()? And if yes, how can it be used? Or do I need to use multiple ST_Union?

Answer (score 0):

ST_Contains take two different parameters of geometry and st_collect function returns multigeometry or collection. In this case,  you don't need to make geometry array. multigeometry also is a geometry. so if i understand correctly you can use a sql like this.

```
select st_contains(
    (
        ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)'), 10)
    ),
    (
    SELECT ST_Collect( mk.geom )
    FROM mydatatable mk 
    WHERE mk.id in ('002', '003', '007')
    )
)
```